# Cannot access apps created for my FB page

Tags: facebook

I have two pages and apps created on both pages. Although the apps on both pages work fine I cannot access the apps on one page to edit them. I need to update them after the timeline switchover. Only 1 app created for one of the pages is shown. The other 4 apps on my other page seem to have vanished. if I log on FB as myself to access the Developers page I only see the one app. Loggin straight into the affected page and trying to access the Dev page redirects me straight back to my page.
I have hours of work that I cannot access! The help from FB is next to useless and hours of searching has turned up nothing. Can anyone advise? The apps exists because I created them! If nobody can advise, does anyone know where I can go to get advise and a response from FB?
Thanks